# Does returning a type with 'static tell the compiler this value doesn't have an associated lifetime or does it make that value static?

Tags: enums, rust, lifetime

I have an enum with a "partial" lifetime: one of its variants contains a borrowed value, and another contains an owning value. I have a function which always returns an enum with the owning variant. In order to make the compiler happy, I have to state that the lifetime for the returned enum is `'static`.

My question is about the real lifetime of the returned enum:

By stating that the lifetime is `'static`, am I just guiding the compiler this enum doesn't have an associated lifetime or am I actually turning that instance to be static?

```rust
pub enum Sometimes<'a> {
    Own(u16),
    Borrow(&'a mut u16),
}

impl<'a> Sometimes<'a> {
    pub fn from_u16(data: u16) -> Sometimes<'static> {
        Sometimes::Own(data)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's exactly what it seems to be: You are telling the compiler that the type returned by `from_u16` will have a lifetime of `'static` associated with it. This lifetime is carried with the enum type itself, not a specific variant.

The type `Sometimes<'static>` is different from any other type `Sometime<'a>` unless `'a` is `'static`. For example, you may not be able to call/return from a function `fn foobar<'a>(foo: Sometime<'a>) -> ...` with values returned from `from_u16` unless `'a` can be made to be `'static` (the compiler will yell at you for promising a generic lifetime `'a` but using a specific lifetime `'static` and not being able to prove that `'a` is in fact `'static`).

Another consequence is that you can't change the value of the thing returned by `from_u16` to `Sometimes::Borrow(&mut u16)` unless that reference is `'static` (which may be what you want). Consider a function `foobar` as above, where the compiler figured that `'a` is `'static` as it was passed what was returned from `from_u16`. Now some code somewhere mutates the values to be a `Sometimes::Borrow`. This is safe only if the lifetime associated with `Sometimes::Borrow` is still `'static` all along, otherwise `foobar` now handles what it supposed was a `'static` lifetime but is, in fact, a dangling reference. That's a paddling.

So no, you can't guide the compiler that there is a variant of enum where the lifetime does not matter. The instance returned is not `'static` by itself, it just carries an associated lifetime of `'static` wherever it goes and the compiler will complain if you try to return some generic lifetime but actually return `'static`.